# getElementsByTagName multiple tags

Tags: getelementsbytagname

I want get all my input and select elements off my page HTML. I've tried `getElementsByTagName('input,select')` but it does not work.

My code HTML and JavaScript:

```js
function myFunction() {
var data =  [];
var data1 = [];
var data2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {

  
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT,SELECT")[i].getAttribute("name"); 
var y = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT,SELECT")[i].getAttribute("type");
var z = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT,SELECT")[i].getAttribute("maxlength");
  data.push(x);
  data1.push(y);
  data2.push(z);
  location.href ="ttt.php?name=" + data + "&active=" + data1 + "&data2=" + data2
}  

}
```

```html
<select name="CIV"><option selected="selected" value=""></option><option selected="selected" value="">Mr</option><option selected="selected" value="">Mme</option></select>
<input type="text" size="20" name="first_name" id="first_name" maxlength="50" class="cust_form" value="">
<input type="text" size="20" name="last_name" id="last_name" maxlength="50" class="cust_form" value="">
<input type="text" size="20" name="address3" id="address3" maxlength="50" class="cust_form" value="">
```

Comment: First, what you are trying to do - passing element tags separated by commas to `getElementsByTagName` - won't work. What are you trying to achieve? You need to change your approach.

Comment: What I want to do is to retrieve all input and select name. When i test var x = document.getElementsByTagName ("INPUT") [i] .getAttribute ("name"); It only returns inputs. But I need input and also select. After I send the varaibles via url

Comment: You can only get them separately. Your best bet is to get them separately and merge the two collections. Summary is that what you are doing is totally wrong. You can't send array via a url as you did. What you will get is `[object Object]` in place of all the `data` and `data1` you are passing to the url. I think you need to first understand JavaScript and how it helps in manipulating values on the DOM.

Comment: when i use this code

Comment: when i use this code document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[i].getAttribute("name");  I get the names of my input elements in url ttt.php?name=first_name,last_name,address3&active=text,text,text&data2=50,50,50. But I do not take the select elements I'm looking for a function that allows me to take all elements input, select, checkbox .....

Comment: Ha, I was wrong about the array to string that I said will return `[object Object]` Check the answer I added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access the elements separately; `INPUT` and `SELECT`. BTW, Select element doesn't have `type` and `maxlength` attributes.

```
function myFunction() {
  var nameData =  [];
  var typeData = [];
  var maxLengthData = [];
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")
  var select = document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT")

  // Targeting the first 9 of elements of input collections and select collections
  // Assuming you understand what you are doing here
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    nameData.push( input[i].getAttribute( 'name' ) );
    nameData.push( select[i].getAttribute( 'name' ) );
    typeData.push( input[i].getAttribute( 'type' ) ); // Select element doesn't have type attribute
    maxLengthData.push( inputt[i].getAttribute( 'maxlength' ) ); // Select elemnt doesn't have maxlength attribute

    // Assuming you understand what you are doing to build your url here
    location.href ="ttt.php?name=" + nameData + "&active=" + typeData + "&data2=" + maxLengthData
  }  

}
```

Please, read more on HTML elements and their attributes. Also, read more on pure JavaScript.

Note: this has not been tested yet. Try it and let me know if it does what you you want it to do.